# Map Activity ANR Issue

Tags: android-intent, mapfragment, android-anr-dialog, mapactivity

I have a navigation drawer activity. At onCreate, i have created a MapFragment using fragment transaction.

```
Fragment fragment = null;
            String newttitl = "TEST";
           fragment = new MapFragment();
     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment, "MAIN");
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("MAIN");
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(newttitl);
```

then i did some actions with drawer items using Intent. For Each item i used separate intent. I have several activities to load. But i used a simple activity to load. When i call **onBackpressed** to finish the activity which i have called, it sometimes give ANR. Please help me to handle this issue off. I don't know how to handle in onPause,onResume.

NaviagtionActivity.java

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);




        //checkConnection();
        boolean isConnected = Connection.isConnected();

        // Check if user is already logged in or not

            Fragment fragment = null;
            String newttitl = "FUEL ON";
            fragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
            if (fragment != null) {

                checkConnection();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment, "MAIN");
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("MAIN");
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(newttitl);
            }


        drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);


        // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
        //displayView(0);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        if(id == R.id.action_search){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search action is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    @Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
        displayView(position);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        Activity activity= null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        String TAG=null;
        boolean isConnected = Connection.isConnected();
        switch (position) {

            case 0:


                // Check if user is already logged in or not

                    fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MAIN");

                    if (fragment != null && !fragment.isVisible()) {
                        // add your code here
                        TAG="MAIN";
                        fragment = new MapFragment();
                        title = "FUEL ON";



                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }



                break;

            case 1:

                        //Launch and/or Bind to service here
                        Intent intent = new Intent(this,CheckActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case 2:

                  intent= new Intent(this,SettingActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case 3:
                intent = new Intent(this, Sample.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case 4:

                // Check if user is already logged in or not

                    intent = new Intent(this, Sample5.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                break;

            case 5:
                intent = new Intent(this, NotificationFragment.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case 6:
                intent= new Intent(this,Sample3.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case 7:
                intent = new Intent(this, Sample2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case 8:
                intent = new Intent(this, HelpFragment.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case 9:
                intent = new Intent(this, AboutFragment.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        if(isConnected) {
            if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment, TAG);
                fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(TAG);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                // set the toolbar title
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
            }
        }
        else {showSnack(false);}
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {

      //  Connection connection = new Connection();
        super.onResume();
        Thread.currentThread().getState();

        Log.e("NavigationResume", String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread())+Thread.currentThread().getState());

    //    Toast.makeText(this,"NAV"+"onResume"+Thread.currentThread().getState(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // register connection status listener
      //  MyApplication.getInstance().setConnectivityListener(this);
//        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();

       // this.unregisterReceiver(connection);
        Log.e("NavigationPause", String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread())+Thread.currentThread().getState());
     //   Toast.makeText(this,"NAV"+"onPause",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK);
        alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to exit ?");
        alertDialog.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

//                        firstName.setEnabled(true);
//                        lastName.setEnabled(true);
//                        mobNum.setEnabled(true);
//                        emailAd.setEnabled(true);
               finish();

                // Write your code here to invoke YES event
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

                // Write your code here to invoke YES event
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected) {
        showSnack(isConnected);
    }

}
```

My MapFragment.

```
package com.example.administrator.login.fragments;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.administrator.login.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;




/**
 * Created by Administrator on 03-08-2016.
 */
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    View rootView;
// Connection detector class

public MapFragment () {
        // Required empty public constructor
        }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment



        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));

        // toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);




        return rootView;


        }

        @Override
        public void onPause()
        {

                super.onPause();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),getContext().toString()+"Pause",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume()
        {
                super.onResume();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),getContext().toString()+"Resume",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

        }
}
```

My Intent

```
 public class Sample extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button applyCode,addCode;
    private EditText editPromocode;
    private CardView promocardView;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.promotions_fragment);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);




    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        //No call for super(). Bug on API Level > 11.
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

       // navigateUpTo(new Intent(this,NavigationActivity.class));
       super.onBackPressed();
       PromotionFragment.this.finish();
        return true;

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        Log.e("Hiii Thread", String.valueOf(Thread.interrupted()));
        Thread.interrupted();
        super.onBackPressed();
        super.finish();

//        new Thread() {
//            @Override
//            public void run() {
//                //If there are stories, add them to the table
//                try {
//                    // code runs in a thread
//                    PromotionFragment.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
//                        @Override
//                        public void run() {
//
//                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"this is PUI thread",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                            Log.e("PromoUI", String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread())+Thread.currentThread().getPriority());
//                            finish();
//                        }
//                    });
//                } catch (final Exception ex) {
//                    Log.i("---","Exception in thread");
//                }
//            }
//        }.start();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
      //Toast.makeText(this,"Promotion"+"onStop",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("PROMOSTOP", String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread()));
        super.finish();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
     //   super.finish();
    //    Toast.makeText(this,this.toString()+"onPause",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //finish();

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("PROMODESTROY", String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread()));
        this.finish();
        super.finish();
//        Fragment fragment=null;
//        fragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
//        if (fragment != null) {
//
//            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
//            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
//            fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment);
//            fragmentTransaction.commit();
//
//        }

      //  Toast.makeText(this,this.toString()+"Destroy",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
```

Comment: Can you show me the code what you wrote in onBackpressed ?

Comment: It is in  inbuilt one. @Thom